# AccountController in MVC 5 and Unity IoC

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, unity-container

I have created a new ASP.NET MVC 5 project with Individual User Authentication in place. I have then gone ahead and installed Unity IoC as a package and configured that by doing the following inside `UnityConfig.cs`:

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(), WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface, WithName.Default);
    container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
}
```

From stuff I read through  Google, this should take care of the fact that Unity would pick the constructor with most parameters. My `AccountController.cs` has the following two constructors.

```
private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

public AccountController()
{
}

public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager )
{
    UserManager = userManager;
    SignInManager = signInManager;
}
```

But still I am experiencing problems. When I navigate to `http://localhost:xxxx/account/login` I get a **404 Error**!

Here is my `RouteConfig.cs`

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Artist",
    url: "{controller}/{urlfriendly}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Artist", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Don't you need to (or, have you) set the `DependencyResolver`? e.g. `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));`

Comment: That is already done in `UnityMvcActivator.cs` in this line `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));`

Comment: Getting a 404 sounds more like you have a routing problem than a problem with DI.

Comment: Added Routing code, I thought so too, but can't figure out anything wrong with the route!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, the problem is with your routes.

Think of routes like a switch case statement in c#. The issue you have is that whenever the first route encounters *any* 3 segment route, it will *always* match. Therefore, any normal `/controller/action/id` will never hit your default route.

There needs to be either 1 or more constraints and/or 1 or more explicit segments in the route in order to ensure it *doesn't* match at some point, or you have basically made an unreachable execution path.

Here is an example with an explicit segment.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Artist",
    url: "Artist/{urlfriendly}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Artist", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: I actually meant to write that, but missed it due to copy / pasting the default. Thanks NightOwl :)